# music21 - Transpose streams to a given key

Tags: python, music21

Is there a function or easy way to transpose a stream to a given key?

I want to use it in a loop, e.g, take a set of major streams and transpose all of then to C major (so then I can do some statistical work with them).

All the transpose tools I saw work with intervals or number of tones, not fixed keys. It shouldn't be so hard to write my function, but I suppose that it has to be already done... Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `s` is a `Stream` (such as a `Score` or `Part`), then `s.transpose('P4')` will move it up a Perfect Fourth, etc.  If you know the key of `s` as `k` major, then `i = interval.Interval(k, 'C')` will let you do `s.transpose(i)` to move from `k` to C.  If you don't know the key of `s`, then `k = s.analyze('key')` will do a pretty decent job of figuring it out (using the Krumhansl probe-tone method).  Putting it all together.

```
from music21 import *
for fn in filenameList:
    s = converter.parse(fn)
    k = s.analyze('key')
    i = interval.Interval(k.tonic, pitch.Pitch('C'))
    sNew = s.transpose(i)
    # do something with sNew
```

This assumes that your piece is likely to be in major.  If not you can either treat it as the parallel major (f-minor -> F-major) or find in `k.alternativeInterpretations` the best major key analysis.  Or transpose it to a minor if it's minor, etc.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I wrote my own code a few days ago (but its not working ok, so maybe I should try this). About the major/minor issue, I use 'analyze' before transposing so I keep only major or minor streams

Comment: Just a little improvement: The code doesn't work because 'k' and 'C' are not Note objects. A correct way may be replacing 'C' by the note.Note('C') and getting a note object from k. For example: tonic = note.Note(pitch = k.pitchFromDegree(1)), and using 'tonic' instead of 'k' in the interval.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed (in the example)